# JPA interceptor / event listener that doesn't fire with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, listener

```
@PostLoad 
public void initThing() { ... }
```

I added that to my entity but it seems on the entity load it's not called...

I use jpa on a spring context without EJB 
Hibernate 3.2.7

We already have some hibernate interceptors (extending EmptyInterceptor) declared inside the "entityInterceptor" of the session factory

Is it possible to mix both styles of interceptor?

Is it possible to use @PostLoad without EJB/EntityManager?

Another reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those interested, i got a response from Steve Ebersole and it seems that when you create your own hibernate SessionFactory, you can't use the JPA annotations like @PostLoad without registering the corresponding EventListener in that session factory...
Actually the entity manager system do all this stuff for you.

So i guess i have to add the EJB3PostLoadEventListener to the session factory

But as in my case i have to make this available just for my subproject, i'll use an hibernate interceptor because they can be session scoped, and also injected this interceptor in an overriden spring HibernateTemplate declaration

Comment: Why not just use hibernate-entitymanager in the first place if you want JPA functionality? You can still use proprietary hibernate stuff if you absolutely need to...

Comment: Because we work on a large project, i'm not architech and i can't easily on my own change things on the core

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe the EJB annotations work without EJB/EntityManager.